# Apple Watch-2 page-based navigation display HTTP data on page changed

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I try to create an **page-based navigation** watch app with **Swift 2**.
My app is below:

[image]

For both interfaces I have unique controllers named **InterfaceController and EconomyInterfaceController**.

In each controller I read some JSON data with function in controller **init()** function

```
func setFeed(url: String) {
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

    let task: NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let data = data {
            do {

                let _data: AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
                if let items = _data!["data"] as? NSArray{
                    self.tableOutlet.setNumberOfRows(items.count, withRowType: "row")
                    for (index, item) in items.enumerate() {
                        if let title = self.JSONString(item["title"]) {
                            if let spot = self.JSONString((item["spot"])) {
                                let news = newsItem(title: title, spot: spot)
                                let row = self.tableOutlet!.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? RowController
                                row!.rowLabel!.setText(news.title)                                }
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch {
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

As I know this is not best way for **HTTP** request because of all request run on main thread and on app startup. This is not my main question but if you have any offer I cannot refuse :)

My main question is if I call **setFeed()** method in **willActivate()** method and set table labels with

```
row!.rowLabel!.setText(news.title)
```

my app works but this is not a good choice because on each time page changed this updates content again and again.

If I call **setFeed()** method in **init()** method and set table labels with

```
row!.rowLabel!.setText(news.title)
```

Only app's first page being displayed and other pages not being displayed. What is wrong here?